# PHP float modulus not working

Tags: php, floating-point, modulus

I wrote a function to add commas and zeros to a number if necessary, but I've gotten stuck at the modulus function. According to my PHP:

```
float(877.5) % 1 == 0 //true
```

Shouldn't `877.5 % 1 == 0.5`?

Comment: `Operands of modulo are converted to integers (by stripping the decimal part) before processing. For floating-point modulo, see fmod(). ` [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) . thanks for asking

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's giving you the reminder of the division what you need is [**fmod**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php),

**fmod** — *Returns the floating point remainder (modulo) of the division of the arguments*

```
echo fmod(877.5, 1); // 0.5
```

Comment: So what's the difference between % and fmod exactly? Is it because it's a float that % does not work?

Comment: Odd, in google chrome inspector, if I type 33.3 % 1 it gives me the float return of 0.3

Comment: @ShannonHochkins - Calculations in Web Consoles are powered by JavaScript, not PHP. If you run `(9.5 % 6)` through JavaScript and PHP, JavaScript will give the answer `3.5` and PHP will give the answer `3`. If you want `3.5` from PHP, you need to ask it: `fmod(9.5, 6)`

Answer (score 1):

No, the modulus operator tells you the remainder of the division. Anything divided by 1 does not have a remainder, so it yields 0.