# Modulo negative floats using "%" and gmp_mod does not work

Tags: php, modulo, gmp

I try to get the result of -0.15 modulo 5 in PHP. 
Following codes always return 0.

```
$mod = ((-0.15) % 5)
$mod = (-0.15 % 5)
$mod = gmp_mod("-0,15", "5");
$mod = gmp_mod(-0.15, 5);
```

When I type "-0.15 mod 5" into google, it returns: 4.85

What is wrong with the code I use in PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP float modulus not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236851/php-float-modulus-not-working)

Comment: Can http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409281/how-is-13-64-13-in-php help you?

Answer (score 0):

According to http://php.net/language.operators.arithmetic, "Operands of modulus are converted to integers (by stripping the decimal part) before processing."

So $mod = 0 % 5, which would be 0.